Some curios sums of Hurwitz zeta-function and Lehmer's totient problem
For all squarefree $k\in \mathbb N$
$$\left|\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\zeta_H(-1,n/k)}{\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\chi_0(n)\zeta_H(-1,n/k)}\right|=\left|\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}1}{\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\chi_0(n)}\right|=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}1}{\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\chi_0(n)}=\frac{k-1}{\phi(k)} \notin \mathbb N_{>1}.$$
$\zeta_H(s,n/k)$ is the Hurwitz zeta function, $\chi_0(n)$ the principial Dirichlet character of modulus k and if Lehmer's totient problem is true, $\frac{k-1}{\phi(k)}$ is not an integer $>1$.
Note, that it's possible to cancel the Hurwitz zeta functions out of the sums!!!
A counter example to Lehmer's totient problem, could be as large as a counter example to the RH.
Consider a generalized riemann zeta function:
$$\zeta_L(s)=\prod_{n\in \mathbb N_{>1}, \phi(n)|n-1}(1-n^{-s})^{-1}.$$
If Lehmer's totient problem is true, $\zeta_L(s)$ equals the riemann zeta function. If there are just finite counter examples to LTP, $\zeta_L(s)$ has the same non-trivial zeros like the riemann zeta function.
If there exists infinite counter examples to LTP, the product of $\zeta_L(s)$ is not an euler-product. Consider $\zeta_L(s)$ has an analytic continuation to the critical strip. Is it possible, that this function has n.-tr. zeros, whose real part is not 1/2?
Are there any heuristic arguments, that Lehmer's totient problem is RH or GRH equivalent?

It Is not clear what is the question, could you please edit?

Both the numerator and the denominator can be simplified using the classical formulas
\begin{align*}
k^s \zeta(s) &= \sum_{n=1}^k \zeta\Bigl( s,\frac nk \Bigr) \\
k^s L(s,\chi) &= \sum_{n=1}^k \chi(k) \zeta\Bigl( s,\frac nk \Bigr).
\end{align*}
Since $\zeta(s,1)=\zeta(s)$, we find that when $k\ge2$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \zeta(s,n/k)}{\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \chi_0(n)\zeta(s,n/k)} &= \frac{\sum_{n=1}^k \zeta(s,n/k) - \zeta(s)}{\sum_{n=1}^k \chi_0(n)\zeta(s,n/k) - \chi_0(k)\zeta(s)} \\
&= \frac{k^s \zeta(s) - \zeta(s)}{k^s L(s,\chi_0) - 0\zeta(s)} \\
&= (1-k^{-s}) \frac{ \zeta(s)}{L(s,\chi_0)} = (1-k^{-s}) \prod_{p\mid k} \bigl( 1-p^{-s} \bigr)^{-1}.
\end{align*}
This holds for all $s\in\Bbb C$ (including the removable singularity at $s=1$) and never used the assumption that $k$ be squarefree. In particular,
$$
\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \zeta(-1,n/k)}{\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \chi_0(n)\zeta(-1,n/k)} = (1-k) \prod_{p\mid k} (1-p)^{-1} = (-1)^{\omega(k)-1} \frac{k-1}{\phi(r(k))}
$$
for $k\ge2$, where $r(k) = \prod_{p\mid k} p$ is the squarefree radical of $k$.

When studying number theory, these equations, which combine L-functions with Hurwitz zeta functions, are the "Holy Grail" of analytic number theory. Riemann and Dirichlet are like "rockstars"! Too bad, that only some people could recognize.
